# Filter a RadGrid When the Enter Key is Pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

In Winform,is there any way to enable radGrid Filtering  only when  Enter key pressed. because I want to filter records from server side (filter from total records in database).
And also need to disable the auto-suggest text from filter control.

I added

```
this.radGridView1.FilterChanged += new GridViewCollectionChangedEventHandler(radGridView_FilterChanged);
```

But this event triggering without hit enter key.
Its possible in web application. But Is there any option available in telerik for Winforms, or how can i do it.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about RadGridView from Telerik UI for WinForms, achieving this with the default filter row would not be easy. However, you can add your own filtering row and handle the filtering in it as you wish. There is also a demo of such case in the Telerik Demo Application, called "Custom filtering row".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Filter a RadGrid When the Enter Key is Pressed

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/filtering/how-to/filter-on-enter